# Select and Delete Multiple Emails in MS Outlook Web App

Tags: email, selection, outlook-web-access

In Microsoft Outlook Web App how does one select multiple or a group of emails in order to delete them? I don't want to select the entire page.

I've tried the normal way of selecting multiple items but this doesn't work.

Comment: What's your OWA version?

Comment: My mistake.Your right. I had Bookmarked the Light Version. Full version saved now. We just got new computers with all new software and switched from Lotus Notes. Finally out of the 90's ! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> modifiers when selecting are what you need.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> - Adds single email to selection

<kbd>shift</kbd> - Adds all emails between selected and previously selected to selection.

Both of these are pretty common between many web and desktop applications.

If this is the answer everyone always gives that is wrong and does not answer your question, could you clarify the exact behavior you wish to have?

Comment: No that dose not work. It only gives two options: Check -box for whole page. Or selecting each one at a time..  I have asked around and everybody including in the office and they what to know also.   Something so simple can't be this hard.......But it is.

Comment: My mistake.Your right. I had Bookmarked the Light Version. Full version saved now. We just got new computers with all new software and switched from Lotus Notes. Finally out of the 90's ! Thank you for your time.

Comment: @G.Bracken  On the light version they often at least implement the ability to shift click from tick box to tick box as a range (if there is a tickbox for each message). Can't say with any authority for the microsoft one but its a pretty standard feature in webmail clients. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are logging into OWA in "Light" mode, which only allows the one-at-a-time check-box functionality as you describe.

[image]

If you login in "heavy" mode (uncheck "Use the light version..."), then you can use the usual <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> methods for multi-select.

Depending on your Exchange and browser version, if you can't uncheck that box (i.e: Exchange 2010 or 2013 and IE11), then it's most likely due to a lack of updates on your Exchange server, as there's a certain update needed before OWA supports IE11 (in anything but light mode), or you're using some other unsupported browser.

Comment: Thank You vary much. You were correct. I had not realized I bookmarked the "Light Version" We just switched from Lotus Notes along with new computers and all new software. We are finally out of the 90's     Thanks again.

Comment: @G.Bracken No problem, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this in Outlook Web App and the old standby Windows methods (select then Shift-select to select a contiguous group, CTL-select to select unconnected multiples) work fine.  I then use either delete key, shift-delete, or right-click and select delete from the context menu.

If you're on a touch screen, I'm afraid someone else will have to help...

Comment: No that dose not work. It only gives two options: Check -box for whole page. Or selecting each one at a time.

Comment: Regular KB came with HP.